# On almost-(multiplicative)-morphisms between infinite groups and the complex numbers

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be an infinite group and $\varphi\colon G\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\exists\,\delta>0, \forall\,a,b\in G,\, |\varphi(ab)-\varphi(a)\varphi(b)|\leq\delta\quad(\mathcal{P})
\end{eqnarray*}
What can be said about $\varphi$? Precisely, is it true that 
$(1)\quad\varphi$ is bounded, or 
$(2)\quad\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ for all $a,b\in G$? 
Let $e$ be the neutral element of $G$. Clearly, if $\varphi(e)\neq 1$, then $|\varphi(a)|\leq\delta|1-\varphi(e)|^{-1}$ for all $a\in G$; hence $\varphi$ is bounded. However, if $\varphi(e)=1$, it’s not clear to me if $\varphi$ remains bounded. I also think that when it’s not bounded, $\varphi$ may end up satisfying $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ for all $a,b\in G$ (my attempts to build counterexamples failed, which makes me feel that the claim might be true)

Note: $\mathcal{P}$ does not define a *quasimorphism* (the landing set is the complex numbers and the property is multiplicative instead of the usual additive one for *quasimorphisms*)

***[cross-posted] https://mathoverflow.net/q/394839/172526***

Comment: Such a map is called a quasi-morphism ; generally people lkooks $R$ valued rather than $C$ valued, but it is not rellay important.. You should read the survey https://www.ams.org/notices/200402/what-is.pdf

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the reference. I can’t see how to define the homogenization process for the way this quasimorphism defined (it’s multiplicative and takes values in the complex plane - it’s not clear to see why $\varphi\left(x^n\right)/n$ has a limit.

Comment: The question "what can be said" is way too open-ended. As for the sentiment "I Also feel that...", it is quite false already for free groups. And so is the sentence "Clearly..."

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mistakenly included 0 in the “clearly...” statement. Do you still think it’s wrong? I edited the problem statement to ask precisely the question “is it true that ... “. As for free groups, I don’t see a counterexample (perhaps)

Comment: Yes, this is still quite wrong. The simplest thing to note is that if $f: G\to {\mathbb C}$ is a (quasi)homomorphism and $h:  G\to {\mathbb C}$ is any bounded function, then $f+h$ is again a quasihomomorphism. But, there are more interesting examples as well.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry to pester, but isn’t trivial that if $\varphi(e)\neq1$, then $|\varphi(a)|$ is bounded by $\delta/|1-\varphi(1)|$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I’m also not sure that perturbing a quasimorphism by adding a bounded function leads to a quasimorphism the way I defined in the problem (multiplicative instead of additive).

Comment: Oh, I seem you are using the nonstandard convention for quasimorphisms, which are usually written additively.

Comment: You should not call such maps quasimorphisms, this name is already taken for maps satisfying the inequality $\forall x, y\in G, |f(xy)- f(x) -f(y)|<const$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan ok! I initially called it $\delta$-*close morphism*, not the sexiest name, but I followed @Thomas’ comment to rename it quasimorphism. I’ll rename it. So I guess all your comments were about the additive version; hence they no longer stand ?

Comment: Yes, my comments were about the additive version and they do not apply to your question. You are right that unless your $\varphi$ is bounded, $\varphi(1)=1$.

Comment: I suggest, asking this question at Mathoverflow, just make sure you add cross-references here and at MO. Also, when (and if) you ask, add a remark that your definition is different from the one of a *quasimorphism*.